# <img> after <h1> does not validate as HTML 4.01 Strict

Tags: html, w3c-validation, html4

My markup is

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>klaymen - About</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Klaymen</h1>
    <img src="resources/klaymen-about.jpg" width="200" alt="Klaymen's about picture">
</body>
```

When I test the document with this validator https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input I get the following error:

> document type does not allow element "IMG" here; missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "DIV", "ADDRESS" start-tag

Clearly I have an `H1`, and `img` is a [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) element which supposed to be allowed in this location, so what is the problem?

Comment: Your link about "flow content" points to a page about HTML5. Different rules!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `div` container.

```
<div>
    <img src=""/>
    <span display: block>Text below the image</span>
</div>
```

This happens because the `body` of a document in this spec cannot contain an inline element like `<img>`, thus, by putting it inside a block element like `<div>`, all's fixed.

Comment: Adding a link to the document specifying this change of spec in the W3C standard http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/#content-model